# Deploying MVC4 site to Azure results in ExtensionAttribute exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure

After watching the key note address from Scott Gu at AspConf I got excited about trying the Windows Azure Web sites with MVC4. I tried deploying an existing MVC application after re-configuring it to target .NET framework 4.0 instead of 4.5 and got the following error.

> Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Since I had already added several NuGet packages I thought it might have something to do with Ninject so I created a new MVC project targeting the .NET 4.0 framework with no NuGet packages and deployed to Windows Azure using the Visual Studio 2012 RC Publish option (right-clicking the Web project) and I still get this error.

Does anyone know what's going on or how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Including full stack trace:

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
>   IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
>   Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +180
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
>   Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +192
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord
>   caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly,
>   RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[]
>   attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean&
>   isVarArg) +115
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +426 
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit) +64
>   WebActivator.AssemblyExtensions.GetActivationAttributes(Assembly
>   assembly) +64    WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods()
>   +143    WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run() +22
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization
>   method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception
>   with the following error message: Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'..]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +423
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization
>   method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception
>   with the following error message: Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'..]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090044 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +256

Comment: After re-deploying with a new project I had a different error as outlined int he following post. I tried their solution and it worked for me with a new sample project. I will try again with the 'real' project that has many more NuGet packages installed and verify this solution works. In short check the 'Remove additional files at destination' in the Settings tab of the Publish dialog with a MVC4 project that has been switched to target the .NET 4.0 framework. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/8903549b-b0ab-4cd8-bbc4-4c7f931715e6/

Comment: @likestoski - if you have solved the issue, please post as an answer to your own question to help others that may stumble with this same question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Publish Web Application wizard if I select Settings | Remove additional files at destination this problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like a Problem with .NET FX references.

According to the ASP.NET MVC 4 release notes, there's an issue with Entity Framework nuget package and downgrading from .NET 4.5 --> .NET 4.
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815

> Changing an ASP.NET MVC 4 project to target 4.0 from 4.5 does not
>   update the EntityFramework assembly reference:  If you change an
>   ASP.NET MVC 4 project to target 4.0 after targetting 4.5 the reference
>   to the EntityFramework assembly will still point to the 4.5 version.
>   To fix this issue uninstall and reinstall the EntityFramework NuGet
>   package.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (others with same exception) could be that your build server has not have the .net 4.0 reference assemblies, after installing .net 4.5 you'll need to copy them from your dev box.

These are typically somewhere like:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

For more details see [Marc's blog post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.nz/2012/09/iterator-blocks-missing-methods-and-net.html)